# csv table data processing questions

Tags: python, excel

i have a table look like this

[image]

I need to add a field for each county the maximum percentage score. for example if 99.03833, then the Anderson County maximum score is HAZ_7. The first row represents score. the numbers at each rows represent the percentage of the score. I need the majority score for each county.

Can any body know how to do it either in excel or in python?

Comment: So you need the text `%HAZ_7` in a new column for that row? And the column title for the maximum value of each row?

Comment: yes. I need the score for the maximum percentage for each row

Comment: So, no then? You are saying you want `99.03833` displayed in the new column?

Comment: A sample of the expected output would be very helpful

Comment: Some sample lines from the csv file would also be useful. Please [edit] your question and it (or them). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Excel solution for column name:

```
=INDEX(C$1:L$1,MATCH(MAX(C2:L2),C2:L2,0))
```

Excel solution for value:

```
=MAX(B2:L2)
```

Comment: this returns a minimum column value, not the maximum. The results is not correct

Answer (score 0):

I will assume this is a pandas DataFrame called `df`. If that is the case, the below python will add a column to your DataFrame called `max` that contains the maximum value of each row.

```
df['max'] = df.loc[:,'%HAZ_1':].max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thats just show the max value, not the haz score. I want the related first row HAZ

Comment: You were unclear in your instructions. When you say "score" I am assuming the value. Say "Column header" or something more direct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in Python.

```
import csv

filename = 'county_data.csv'
output_filename = 'county_data2.csv'

def maxelements(names, seq):
    """ Return corresponding names of the position(s) of the largest element in sequence. """
    max_value = max(seq)
    return [names[i] for i, v in enumerate(seq) if v == max_value]

with open(filename, 'r') as infile, open(output_filename, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    fieldnames = next(reader)  # assume first row contains field names
    writer.writerow(fieldnames + ['Max'])  # plus name of new field
    haz_fields = fieldnames[2:]
    for row in reader:
        row = row[:2] + [float(elem) for elem in row[2:]]  # convert haz fields to numbers
        maxfields = maxelements(haz_fields, row[2:])
        writer.writerow(row + maxfields)
```

Here's a small sample input cvs file:

```
County,FIPS,%HAZ_1,%HAZ_2,%HAZ_3,%HAZ_4,%HAZ_5,%HAZ_6,%HAZ_7,%HAZ_8,%HAZ_9,%HAZ_10
Anderson County,48001,0,0,0,0,0,0,99.03833,0.961668,0,0
Andrews County,48003,0,0,0,0,0,0,26.08,73.92,0,0
Angelina County,48005,0,0,0,0,0,62.41924,37.58076,0,0,0
Aransas County,48007,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

And here's what was written to the output file:

```
County,FIPS,%HAZ_1,%HAZ_2,%HAZ_3,%HAZ_4,%HAZ_5,%HAZ_6,%HAZ_7,%HAZ_8,%HAZ_9,%HAZ_10,Max
Anderson County,48001,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,99.03833,0.961668,0.0,0.0,%HAZ_7
Andrews County,48003,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,26.08,73.92,0.0,0.0,%HAZ_8
Angelina County,48005,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,62.41924,37.58076,0.0,0.0,0.0,%HAZ_6
Aransas County,48007,0.0,0.0,100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,%HAZ_3
```

**Note:** The `maxelements()` function returns a list because it's possible for there to be two or more `%HAZ#` fields with the same maximum value in them (although that doesn't occur in the sample input). The code won't necessarily handle that case properly, mostly because you haven't described what you would want to happen in such a situation.

It that's not a concern, you could use the following version of it—essentially a one-liner—that simply returns the index of the first:

```
def maxelements(names, seq):
    """ Return corresponding names of the position(s) of the largest element in sequence. """
    return [names[seq.index(max(seq))]]
```